# Understanding the logic of an Excel INDEX formula which incorporates the MATCH function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm doing an online Excel course and I'm trying to wrap my head around the internal logic of the formulas I'm being taught.  So far, so good, for the most part.  However, I'm trying to figure out the internal logic of a particular formula which incorporates both the INDEX and MATCH features, and I'm not getting anywhere.

The situation is this:  I have to write a formula to search the following array.  The formula must use INDEX and MATCH.  Here's a picture of the array

[image]

The values I have to search for are supposed to be input by a user.  So the user chooses a year from the list in column A, and then chooses either 'Impressions', 'Clicks', or 'Transactions' from the list along the top (cells B1 to D1).

For example, if the user picked 2004 and 'Clicks', the formula should return the value for `C6` because that's the cell at the intersection of the row with 2004 in it, and the column which is headed 'Clicks'.

Here's the formula that I wrote for it:

[image]

In the formula, cell G2 is where the user picks any year from 2000 to 2016 using a drop-down menu.  Cell G3 is where the user picks either 'Impressions', 'Clicks', or 'Transactions' from another drop down menu.

So the above formula should be telling Excel: *Look through cells A2-A18 for whatever the user has put in G2.  Then, look through cells B1-D1 for whatever the user has put in G3.  Then, once you've found those values, look for the cell where they intersect and return that value.*

The problem is that the formula always returns the results one cell to the *left* of the cell that the user has picked.  I can't understand why that is.  I know how to *fix* it; I just change the last part of the formula to `MATCH(G3, A1:D1, 0))` (so change B1 to A1).  The thing is, knowing how to fix it just isn't good enough for me.  I need to know why the original formula doesn't work.  It *should* work, as far as I can tell.  I'm asking Excel to find either 'Impressions', 'Clicks', or 'Transactions' and all those options are available in `B1:D1`, so I don't see why the formula only works if I type `A1:D1`.

If anyone could explain the underlying logic for me I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match returns the relative location in the range as a Long.

With `MATCH("Clicks", A1:D1, 0)`  The relative location is the third cell in that range as a long, `3`.

With `MATCH("Clicks", B1:D1, 0)`  The relative location is the Second cell in that range as a long, `2`.

This number is passed to the INDEX range.  With the first formula it returns the 3rd column in `A2:D18` which is Column `C` and with the second it returns the second column which is Column `B`.

To avoid this always make the rows or columns match between the INDEX and the MATCHES:

```
=INDEX(A2:D18,MATCH(G2,A2:A18,0),MATCH(G3, A1:D1, 0))
```

Or

```
=INDEX(B2:D18,MATCH(G2,A2:A18,0),MATCH(G3, B1:D1, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for that clear explanation.  Much appreciated.